# How to use the elements in array method into main?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to use the elements of array `comNumber`, in `ranNumber()` method
but when I using this in `main()` it only shows the address of array.
How can I fix this problem?

```
public class BaseballGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseballGame bGame = new BaseballGame();
        System.out.println(bGame.ranNumber());


    }

    public int[] ranNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] comNumber = new int[3];
        for(int i=0; i<comNumber.length; i++) {
            comNumber[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                if (comNumber[i] == comNumber[j]) {
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return comNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it just don't print it.

```
int[] result  = bGame.ranNumber();
```

Use `result` now in your main method.

If you want to see what is returned,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseballGame bGame = new BaseballGame();
    int[] result  = bGame.ranNumber();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bGame.ranNumber()` will return an `int[]`, and arrays are objects in java. So Calling `System.out.println(bGame.ranNumber())` will call the `toString` method of array under the hood. The default implementation of `toString` in class Object will print that address. That's the reason you get the address of that array instead of the real elements in the array.

If you want to see the real elements you should do:

```
int[] result = bGame.ranNumber();
for(int i=0; i < result.length; i++){
    System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

or

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(result));
```